# DirectoryService hogging memory

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, opendirectory

My DirectoryService memory usage goes as high as 1GB, with nothing interesting happening to cause it to get that high. It is a stock macos server configuration on the mac mini

What is the problem and how do I fix it

Comment: I've seen this happen on clients when the server they were bound to isn't available, but not on a server. Can you provide any logs? Console should have its own section for DirectoryService. Make sure you're running the latest version of OS X Server.

Comment: I'll see if it's trying to talk to the other server. Perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: I will add it as an answer and then you can check it off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen on clients when the server they were bound to isn't available, but not on a server. Can you provide any logs? Console should have its own section for DirectoryService. Make sure you're running the latest version of OS X Server.